# Continuing for loop when exception occurs

Tags: python, for-loop

I would like for the loop to keep going even exception is generated at first iteration. How to do this?

```
mydict = {}
wl = ["test", "test1", "test2"]
    
try:
  for i in wl:
   a = mydict['sdf']
   print(i)
            
except:
       # I want the loop to continue and print all elements of list, instead of exiting it after exception
       # exception will occur because mydict doesn't have 'sdf' key
    pass
```

Comment: Move `try` / `except` inside loop body

Answer (score 1):

You can use `dict.get()`. It will return `None` if the key not exist. You can also specify default value in `dict.get(key, default_value)`

```
for i in wl:
    a = mydict.get('sdf')
    print(i)
```

Answer (score 0):

The best I can advice is to move the try inside the loop as below:

```
mydict = {}
wl = ["test", "test1", "test2"]
for i in wl:
    try:
        a = mydict['sdf']
        print(i)

    except:
        continue
```

Comment: This is incorrect. The `print` will be skipped.

Comment: Those two lines of code are independent, so you could just move the `print` to be first.

Comment: Also, using a bare `except` that catches all exceptions is bad practice. Only catch the exceptions that you know might be raised.

Answer (score 0):

This is my approach for your problem
Hope its work for you as you want

```
mydict = {}
wl = ["test", "test1", "test2"]

for i in wl:
    try:
        a = mydict['sdf']
    except:
        pass
    print(i)
```